# Make GitKraken commit graph more like githubs network

Tags: github, gitkraken

I like GitKraken apart from the commit graph which I personally find really hard to read what's happening. Compare that to what I think is a really intuitive commit graph, [githubs network](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/network). Is there any way to get it to look more like githubs? At the very least display the graph horizontally?

Comment: I'm afraid as of now there are very few options to individualize the commit graph. I.e. what you want to achive is not possible.